# python setattr for dynamic method creator with decorator

Tags: python, decorator, factory, python-decorators, setattr

I have a class which has multiple methods defined.

```
import mat
class Klass(object):

    @mat.sell(mat.CanSet):
    def method1(self):
        return None

    @mat.sell(mat.CanSet):
    def method2(self):
        return 'value2'
```

Imagine I have 10 methods that I need to populate for this 'Klass'. I want to generate these methods without explicitely writing them all. So I want to do a factory that does setattr for each method. Problem is that I do following and the last method has the last value. Each do not get its related value but value10. Also below solution does not implement the decorator, I have no idea how to do assign the decorator

```
class Klass(object):
    pass

list1 = [('method1', 'value1'), ('method2', 'value2').....('method10', 'value10')]

for each in list1:
    method_name, method_value = each
    setattr(Klass, method_name, lambda self: method_value)
```

So when I do following....

```
k = Klass()
print k.method1(), method2()...., method10()
```

it all results in value10 for each method. Do not understand why ?
Plus, can anyone help on how to implement the decorator with one attribute ?
PS: if you have suggestion that does not use 'setattr', that would be welcomed as well.

Comment: Interesting, if you do it like this: `list1 = [('method1', lambda x: 'value1'), ('method2', lambda x: 'value2'), ('method10', lambda x: 'value10')]` it works. I can only *guess* here... I think in the first case the lambda ends up being a single function (and you overwrite it, hence yielding the last value). But I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the `lambda` to create each method, you are binding it to the currently-local scope. That scope has a single instance of a variable named `method_value`, and it is being set to a new value after each loop. Because each `lambda` refers to this one local variable, they all see the same value (e.g., the last value that was set).

If you create the lambda in a different method, it will have a different scope, and you can therefore get the desired behavior:

```
class Klass(object):
        pass

list1 = [('method1', 'value1'), ('method2', 'value2'), ('method10', 'value10')]

def make_attr(value):
    return lambda self: value

for method_name, method_value in list1:
    setattr(Klass, method_name, make_attr(method_value))

c = Klass()
print c.method1(), c.method2(), c.method10()  # "value1, value2, value10"
```

Here, `make_attr` creates a new scope, and so there are unique instances of the variable `value`, one for each lambda created.

You can also use a nice trick to create a lambda-scoped variable inline, as follows:

```
lambda self, val=method_value: val
```

Here, `val` is assigned the value of `method_value` **at the time of the lambda declaration**, giving each instance of lambda its own value. This lets you use the more compact:

```
for method_name, method_value in list1:
    setattr(Klass, method_name, lambda self, val=method_value:val))
```

Finally, Marti points out in [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135707/925478) how to modify my `make_attr` function to apply the desired decorator:

```
def make_attr(value):
    return mat.sell(mat.CanSet)(lambda self: value))
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I suspected something like that was happening in OP code.. Lambdas sure are scary

Comment: Thanks a bunch Myk, this addresses the method_value, any idea how would I have this decorator for each of the methods generated ?

Comment: @LuckyStarr I edited the answer showing how to apply the desired decorator

Answer (score 6):

Myk Willis answer explains the problem with the scope of the method_value variable. I'll try to expand on it to answer your other doubts.

Regarding the decorator, and how to apply it when producing the methods programatically: it becomes easier once you understand how decorators work in Python. The thing is, they are just functions. A decorator is a function that receives a function and returns a function. The @ syntax is just syntactic sugar that applies the indicated decorator to the decorated function in a more convenient way.

So this:

```
@my_decorator
def my_function():
    ...
```

Will do exactly the same as this:

```
def my_function():
    ...

my_function = my_decorator(my_function)
```

The same applies to your original example. This:

```
@mat.sell(mat.CanSet):
def method1(self):
    return None
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
def method1(self):
    return None

method1 = mat.sell(mat.CanSet)(method1)
```

This one is a bit more complicated, because mat.sell is not a decorator, but rather a function that returns a decorator; hence the double call: first we call mat.sell, passing it the mat.CanSet parameter, and that call returns a decorator that we use to wrap method1.

Knowing this, modifying Myk's answer to apply your decorator is simple:

```
class Klass(object):
    pass

list1 = [('method1', 'value1'), ('method2', 'value2'), ('method10', 'value10')]

def make_attr(value):
    return mat.sell(mat.CanSet)(lambda self: value)

for method_name, method_value in list1:
    setattr(Klass, method_name, make_attr(method_value))
```

Note the change in make_attr(); instead of returning the fabricated method straight away, we pass it first through the decorator and return its return value instead.

As for this:

> Plus, can anyone help on how to implement the decorator with one attribute ? PS: if you have suggestion that does not use 'setattr', that would be welcomed as well.

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you perhaps want to turn your methods into properties? Can you tell us what mat.sell does? It might help us to get a clearer picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the explanation Marti, not only it explains decorator in detail but also resolves the issue. It would be interesting to see, however, if I can just apply the decorator on top of 'def make_attr(value):' and return simply value in place of your suggestion. I'll give it a try today.